# CSS Div 100% with float:left

Tags: html, css

Agrh, CSS - the bane of my life.  Can someone help out here?

I'm trying to get the following div layout:

```
*******************************************************************************
*aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc*
*aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc*
*******************************************************************************
```

Currently my styles look like this:

```
#container {
height:50px;
}

#a {
float:left;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}

#b {
float:left;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}

#c {
float:left;
width:100%;
height:50px;
}

<div id="container">
   <div id="a" />
   <div id="b" />
   <div id="c" />
</div>
```

But this is causing the following to happen (div c drops below the others):

```
********************************************************************************
*aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb                                                       *
*aaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbb                                                       *
*cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc*
*cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc*
********************************************************************************
```

What needs to change to fix this?  Thanks.

---

**Additional info:**

- a and b must have fixed pixel widths.
- This is a simplified example - in reality the divs have borders which must not overlap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand div to max width when float:left is set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017880/expand-div-to-max-width-when-floatleft-is-set)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just don't `float` the last `div` then its gonna work. Also remove the 100% width and give it a left margin of the width of your two fixed width divs. This should look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YMQbh/

Comment: Thanks.  That jsfiddle is a nice tool!

Comment: Thanks for this simple and yet well explained answer

Answer (score 3):

Don't float the "c" div. As a block element, it will naturally take up the whole horizontal width of the viewport.

What you want to do is to simply use a margin on the left side of "c" to give "a" and "b" room beside "c"

Try this:

```
#container {
height:50px;
}

#a {
float:left;
width:50px;
height:50px;
border: 1px #000 solid; /* takes up 2px width - 1px on either side */
}

#b {
float:left;
width:50px;
height:50px;
border: 1px #000 solid; /* takes up 2px width - 1px on either side */
}

#c {
/*   2x 50px wide div elements = 100 px
 * + 2x  1px left borders      =   2 px
 * + 2x  1px right borders     =   2 px
 *                              =======
 *                               104 px
 */
margin-left: 104px; 
}
```

Comment: Without the float, the borders of c overlap with the borders of a and b - this causes problems.

Comment: @UpTheCreek: borders are part of the total width of an element. You need to take them into consideration when determining your margin-left on #c. For example, if #a and #b each have a 1px border, and assuming no margins/padding which would also add width, their total width would be 50px for content, and 2px for the border (1px left + 1px right), giving them a total width of 52px each, so #c would need to have a margin-left of 104px, rather than the 100px I assume you tried.

Comment: This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208939/padding-on-floating-elements/4209218#4209218) I wrote earlier should clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

first of all its better to have a container with a fixed width. The next thing is that the 100% with of "c" is relative to the container, so it will spann the whole container width.

**Update:**
To say it more precise: the c div needs no floating an no width. Like others already said: A div (as blocklevel element) spans by itselfe the whole width.

Comment: Thanks.  So there's no way of having the third div expand to fill the remaining space?

Comment: sadly we'll have to wait or ie to catch up

Comment: @meo: I *much* prefer fixed width to fluid/elastic/etc. You have a consistent frame of reference, and don't need to worry about the browser shrinking so far that things randomly overlap, nor that the browser will expand so far that your lines are so long that they affect readability, or that you have too much whitespace between elements. It's like drawing on a sheet of paper - if I draw a box in the (horizontal) middle of a piece of paper, it lands right where I want it, just like a fixed width design. It's not necessarily *better*, but it does tend to be easier.

Comment: I dont think you can say fixed is better then a fluid design. Both types have theyr reason to be. For webapps it where you have a lot of information on the screen it totaly makes sense to use a fluid layout.

Answer (score 1):

I think just leaving out the width attribute at all for the c div should do the work. Normally DIVs will span the whole width they can get. This example worked for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #a {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            float: left;

            background-color: #ffff00;
        }

        #b {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            float: left;
            background-color: #ff00ff;
        }

        #c {
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #00ffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without and width on c, it just expands wide enough to hold to contents - maybe becuase it's float:left?

Comment: Yapp. Just leave this out as my example showed. And by the way. Use Firebug! There you can easily add/remove/disable/change css properties while viewing the page. That way i figure out most of my CSS errors.

Comment: But without the float the borders are messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than floating `#c`, I'd give it a `margin-left` and leave the `width` as automatic.

Comment: Tried that, but unfortunately without the float on c, the borders overlap with a and b causing problems.

Comment: You can also set a margin on `#b` and tweak `#b`'s and `#c`'s margin depending on your borders.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<div style='width:200px;background:yellow;float:left'>One</div>
<div style='width:200px;background:orange;float:left'>Two</div>
<div style='background:khaki'>Three</div>
```

Can adjust `One` and `Two` widths as needed. Tested working in FF 3.6, IE 8, Safari 4.0, Chrome 3.195.

**EDIT**

Now, with borders:

```
<div style='width:200px;background:yellow;float:left;border:1px solid red;margin:0 -1px;'>One</div>
<div style='width:200px;background:orange;float:left;border:1px solid green;margin:0 -1px'>Two</div>
<div style='background:khaki;border:1px solid black;margin-left:400px'>Three</div>
```

**EDIT 2**

Non-overlapping borders (and contrasting colors), hot off the press:

```
<div style='width:200px;background:yellow;float:left;border:1px solid red;margin:0 -1px;'>One</div>
<div style='width:200px;background:orange;float:left;border:1px solid blue;margin:0 -1px 0 1px'>Two</div>
<div style='background:purple;border:1px solid orange;margin-left:403px'>Three</div>
```

Comment: Then the borders of c interfere with the borders of a and b.

Comment: Borders? Where are the borders in your example? But give me a minute, I'll put in borders.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was showing a simplified example - I didn't realise they were important until i tried removing the float.

Comment: your updated example won't work. You need to accommodate the borders into the margin-left on #c as well. Display width != width property.

Comment: @Agent, @Up - Yes, as @Agent said, the border for #c will be overlapped by the border on #b. Easy fix though, just change to `margin-left:401px`, or see edit 2 for all borders non-overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
float:left
width:100% /*for liquid layout*/
width:960px /*fixed layout*/
height:50px;
}

#a {
float:left;
width:50px;
/*or*/
width:5%;
height:50px;
}

#b {
float:left;
width:50px;
/*or*/
width:5%;
height:50px;
}

#c {
float:left;
width:90%;
/*or*/
width:860px; /* subtract the sum of the container a+b from the container c. */
height:50px;
}

<div id="container">
   <div id="a" />
   <div id="b" />
   <div id="c" />
</div>
```

If you add padding,margin right or left or both you must subtract them from the total width too.

Comment: I should have added in the question, that a and b must have pixel widths.

Comment: That's why I've added two values (in px and in %)